# disable form action redirect when using curl to load a page

Tags: php, redirect, curl

Could someone give me an idea on how not to redirect the page when using cUrl.
I mean, i got this code:

```
$url = "http://somesite.com/submit.php?name=" . $email . "&email=" . $email;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

$curl_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo "Hello!";
```

What happens is that inside the `submit.php` there is a form that autosubmits using javascript. the `submit.php` does not continue since it will redirect to the form's action page.

What curl options should I add on the code to make `submit.php` continue without the form action taking over the page and run the rest of the code of `submit.php`?

> submit.php

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
?>


<form method="post" action="actionpage.php" name="myform">
    ....
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 document.forms["myform"].submit();
 </script>
```

Comment: cURL doesn't support javascript so I suspect something else is wrong here

Comment: if that js script you're talking about is in the file which handles the data , I guess , there is nothing you can do.

Comment: even if the javascript is just submitting the form? by the way i used this code to submit the form `document.forms["myform"].submit();`.

Comment: @xiomai no javascript will be executed, even a form submit. Could you post submit.php?

Comment: @lamplightdev ok. edited the question to include the submit.php page

Answer (score 0):

add this to prevent redirects:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

Comment: tried this but it still redirects me to the form action page.